# Using pipe for writing strings to a windows cmd running a spy app

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, stdin, pipe

Using Windows7 64-bit and Python 2.6.6 32-bit

I'm trying to create a spy window that my application can spawn and write text to so it can be displayed. The window is simply cmd.exe run in a process with Popen, with stdin=PIPE, running a spy application that reads from stdin and writes to stdout. The main application writes to the the subprocesses stdin with strings. I can run the code below with no errors but the text written to the spy is never displayed. Any pointers on what I may be doing incorrectly?

Here's the code for the main object:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class SpyWin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SpyWin, self).__init__()
    def open(self):
        self._spy = Popen(["start", "cmd" , "/k", "python spy_win_mon.py"], shell=True, stdin=PIPE)

    def write(self, s=""):
        self._spy.stdin.write(s)
        self._spy.stdin.flush()

def main():
    sw = SpyWin()
    sw.open()
    sw.write("It works!\r\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here's the spy_win_code.py code that gets executed in the subprocess:

```
import sys

def main():
    def do_it(s):
        sys.stdout.write(s)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    while True:
        s = sys.stdin.readline()
        do_it(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried `self._spy = Popen([sys.executable, "spy_win_mon.py"], stdin=PIPE)`? Call `self._spy.poll()` to check whether the child process has finished (unsuccessfully in this case).

Comment: I added a loop to SpyWin main: print sw._spy.poll() and get nothing but None. Shouldn't returncode be something other than None?  BTW... the window that pops up is titled "C:Windows\system32\cmd.exe - python spy_win_mon.py"

Comment: `None` means that the process is running. To fix the buffering issue, try `Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'spy_win_mon.py'], stdin=PIPE, bufsize=0)`.

Comment: Thanks, but no that doesn't do it: it doesn't open another window and it prints to the stdout of the same from which I ran spy_win.py. Also added shell=True and get the same thing.

Comment: there are multiple issues in your code. It might not be enough to fix just the buffering issue. Let's fix issues **one at a time**: first, make it work in the same cmd window. **Then** ask: how do I change this **working code** to display the output in a new console (even if it may change the code substantially)? Consider using a real GUI e.g., using Tkinter instead of spawning new console windows.